# Sum of all number in range given divided by 3 and 5 and show the range of number as a list

Tags: python, list, range

```
def main(start,end):

    range(start,end)
    total=0
    for nums in range(start,end):
        if nums%3 ==0 or nums%5==0:
            total=(total)+(nums)
    return total

print(main(int(input("enter start ")),int(input("enter end "))))
```

If I input 1 to 100 answer will be 2318

How do I print the number range list without inputting again?

```
print(list(range(start,end)))
```

For example I want `[1,2,3,4,...,99]` but without inputting but using the original input given above

Comment: Save what *main* returns in a variable?

Comment: You can just save the nums variable in your code to a list if required or you can print is there itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is helps you

```
def main(start,end):
    total=0
    l = []
    for nums in range(start,end):
        l.append(nums)

        if nums%3 ==0 or nums%5==0:
            total=(total)+(nums)
    print(l)

    return total


print(main(int(input("enter start ")),int(input("enter end "))))
```

Output:

```
enter start 1
enter end 100
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60, 61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 66, 67, 68, 69, 70, 71, 72, 73, 74, 75, 76, 77, 78, 79, 80, 81, 82, 83, 84, 85, 86, 87, 88, 89, 90, 91, 92, 93, 94, 95, 96, 97, 98, 99]
2318
```

Comment: hmm didnt think of using array will try

Answer (score 0):

Base on the example output that you gave try this:

```
def main(start,end):

    total=0
    num = []
    for nums in range(start,end):
        if nums%3 ==0 or nums%5==0:
            total=(total)+(nums)
        num += [nums]
    return list(num), total 

print(main(int(input("enter start ")),int(input("enter end "))))
```

Comment: i didn't think i meant module but appreciate the help

Answer (score 0):

One Liner. Hope it helps.

```
main = lambda x, y: sum(a if a % 3 == 0 or a % 5 == 0 else 0 for a in range(x, y))
print(main(1, 100))
# Output
2318
```